# numpy.fft.fft causes python to exit with no traceback

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to compute the discrete Fourier transform of a signal. When I execute the sample code below, python exits with no traceback or other console output of any kind. My environment is using numpy=1.15.4 and for compatibility reasons cannot upgrade to a newer version.

```
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0,10,1000)
signal = np.sin(t)
sp = np.fft.fft(signal)
```

Comment: This code works. I have checked by last version (py3) and 1.15.4 (py2). It is probably for your system hardware weakness, particularly your system's *rams*. If you are using PyCharm, try it by another software, too. PyCharm is a little heavy working.

Comment: I think you're right, I have checked with other colleagues and this works fine for them with an identical conda environment. I ended up upgraded to numpy=1.18.5 and spending the required hours resolving environment conflicts, but at least now I can use the np.fft.fft function!